# How to disable the scheduler of the binding of the viewmodel in Sencha ExtJS v6.0.2?

Tags: asynchronous, extjs, data-binding, viewmodel, scheduler

Correct me if I am wrong but I think there is a scheduler that is by default set to a ticker of 5ms for the bindings of the viewmodel.

In other words we notice that when a `set` command is executed the value is not immediately set but there is a small delay.

We are afraid that this asynchronous/parallel programming is causing some instability issues and racing conditions in our application.

**Is there a way to disable the scheduler completely, globally, for all viewmodels and all bindings of our application?**

I guess we are looking something similar of executing the `notify` method immediately.

We understand that this might make the application a little bit more "heavy" and slower but this is not of the main concern right now.

Comment: You better not use [`viewModel`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/guides/application_architecture/view_model_internals.html#application_architecture-_-view_model_internals_-_scheduling_and_dependencies)s in this case...

Comment: We are not at a position that this is an option. The project is quite big already and we cannot revert to listener events for everything. As expected the problems occured when the complexity was increased :)

Comment: From an erased answer I must say that setting the timer of the scheduler to zero causes the application to crash when initializing. Setting timer to the minimum of 1 millisecond makes things work again (default is 5 ms)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is extend [Ext.util.Scheduler](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/Ext.util.Scheduler.html), override the scheduling code.
Then override [Ext.app.ViewModel](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/Ext.app.ViewModel.html) to define your own ViewModel class, which will override your the scheduler code. And whenever you create an instance for viewmodel, just use your class than inbuild class.